# C# Winforms RDLC report Static crosstab columns

Tags: c#, static, report, rdlc, crosstab

I have access database where I have payments table. I am loading this table using adapter in c# and fill a dataset to be used as a data source for RDLC crosstab report. Results are as expected. But my problem is that the report does not show all possible columns that may appear in the future while adding more data.

My question is how to specify all required columns to be displayed in RDLC crosstab report even there exists no data for them?

This is my basic code:

```
string sql = "select* from [payments]";
try
{
   using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(myGlobals.connString))
      {
          using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn))
          {
             DataSet ds = new DataSet();
             adapter.Fill(ds, "regPayments");
             frmReport report = new frmReport();
             BindingSource bs = new BindingSource(ds, "regPayments");
             report.ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("dsRegPayments", bs));
             report.ReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Kindergarten.Report10.rdlc";
             report.Show();
          }
      }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of what you are talking about, and elaborate on what you mean by 'the report does not show all possible columns that may appear in the future'? Are you talking about someone adding columns to the Access table and having the report automatically pick them up?

Comment: I mean for example, there exist some payments for Jan, Feb and March. But in my crosstab, I need to display all 12 months eventhough there is no payment for those months

Answer (score 0):

Change to a SQL Data connection if you are using SQL and if not make sure you request schema data.

Have a look at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.missingschemaaction(v=vs.110).aspx) and you know that the schema is not always provided.

```
// Assumes a valid connection string to an Access database.
static void CreateOleDbAdapter(string connectionString)
{
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    adapter.SelectCommand =
        new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Categories ORDER BY CategoryID");
    adapter.SelectCommand.Connection =
        new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
    adapter.MissingMappingAction = MissingMappingAction.Error;
    adapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.Error;
}
```